# Java - Order of expansion of RequestMapping and Variables

Tags: java

I'm not sure how `@RequestMapping` works and can't test this but I have the code and need to understand to troubleshoot something.

If the URL request is `/view/game1` and in the line `String testString` is the `{service}` and `"service"` variable already both expanded to `/view/game1, request, game1, String.class`? Like is it expanded during `@RequestMapping` and then also expanded during `testString` initialization?

Also during which stage is the expansion happening? There is `@RequestMapping` then `testString` and `MyClass service = MyClass.getName(testString)`.

```
@RequestMapping("/view/{service}")
public ServiceResponse TESTService(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
{
 String testString = bindTestVariable("/view/{service}", request, "service", String.class);
 MyClass service = MyClass.getName(testString);
 return service;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no "expansion" going on in that code. There is "extraction" (or "parsing") of part of the URL path, which happens when the `bindTestVariable()` method is called.

You should however let Spring do that, using [`@PathVariable`](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-pathvariable).

Also, Java naming convention is for method names to start with lowercase letter.

```java
@GetMapping("/view/{service}")
public ServiceResponse testService(@PathVariable("service") String service)
{
    return MyClass.getName(service);
}
```

Comment: so when bindTestVariable is called first argument `"/view/{service}"` becomes `"/view/game1"` right? I mean the `game1` is from the URL and not from any of the code. That's what I'm trying to figure out because for some reason the class is returning empty string and maybe it might be some other class but I had to understand this before checking other things

Comment: Also what about the second argument `"service"`? Does it get extracted during the bindTestVariable()?

Comment: @anon No, `"/view/{service}"` doesn't *become* `"/view/game1"`, if anything, it's the other way around. The `"/view/game1"` path is retrieved from `request`, then matched against `"/view/{service}"`, which means that `service = "game1"`. Since `bindTestVariable()` was told to return the value of `service`, it returns `"game1"`. With Spring's `@PathVariable`, Spring will do the same matching and call your method with `"game1"` as the parameter value.

Comment: So the third "service" argument is just to tell what to return? correct? The actual function is called "bindPathVariable()" though I thought I would rename it assuming it was something private though it sounds like its some how related to `@PathVariable`.